# jquery UI Datepicker getDate returns current date if the format has been set to "D d"

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
 $("#datepickerStart").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "D d",
            showAnim: "slideDown",
            onSelect: function (dateText, d) {                               
            }               
        });
```

later the below line always returns current date even though I have changed the date picker date (on UI)

```
console.debug($("#datepickerStart").datepicker("getDate"));
```

When I comment out the format option it works all right!

What's going on please....

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be datepicker UI bug/issue.

When i tried to use the DD d format , i found that first selection of date returns Current Date. But , if you re-select the same date again then correct date is displayed.See the Log file ,

[image]

But, when i used a different date format `dd/mm/yy` it was behaving correctly,

[image]

So, For a workaround you can exploit the datepicker [altField](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) option for solving your issue.

You can fetch the date from the `altField` instead of the **datePicker**,

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "DD d",
        altField: "#actualDate",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function (date, d) {
            console.debug("Wrong Date : " + $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate"));
            console.debug("Correct Date : " + $("#actualDate").val());
        }
    });
```

#### Here is the [example for altField](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/323/)

Hope this help you.

Comment: thanks much @runcorn.. i like your research. I had already used a similar work around by using " <input type="text" hidden id='StartTimeHidden' />" and storing the correctly formatted date in it. Works all right, However there is another issue now, which your code seems to have too, due to this being a jQuery UI bug. And it is that the currently selected date still remains as current date and not what has been selected in the date picker!